# Show that $(Tp)(x)=\int^x_{-\infty} f(s) ds$ is linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Show that $(Tp)(x)=\int^x_{-\infty} f(s) ds \;$  where $p(x)$ and $f(s)$ are continuous functions is linear operator

as my knowledge :   $(Tp)(ax+by)=\int^{ax+by}_{-\infty} f(s) ds \;$  but how we can go for further

Comment: You rather need to compute $T(\lambda p + \mu q)(x)$. And your definition of $T$ does not mention a function called $p$.

Comment: @tristan..thank you but not get the naswet

Comment: @tristan...$T(\lambda p + \mu q)(x)=\int ^x_{-\infty} f(s) ds $

Comment: I do not understand what $T$ is. What is the definition of $Tp$ when $p$ is a continuous function ?

Comment: Your $T$ is constant, so it is not linear.